# ARM template to create database in already existing SQL managed instance

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I want to create a SQL database inside already existing SQL managed instance.

Microsoft provided this template, but it has child resource considering parent will be SQL managed database. But in our case we would like to create only database not SQL managed instance.

[enter link description here][1]

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/managedinstances/databases?tabs=json

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases",
  "apiVersion": "2021-02-01-preview",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "properties": {
    "autoCompleteRestore": "bool",
    "catalogCollation": "string",
    "collation": "string",
    "createMode": "string",
    "lastBackupName": "string",
    "longTermRetentionBackupResourceId": "string",
    "recoverableDatabaseId": "string",
    "restorableDroppedDatabaseId": "string",
    "restorePointInTime": "string",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "string",
    "storageContainerSasToken": "string",
    "storageContainerUri": "string"
  }
}
```

Please help us.

Thanks

Comment: That resource will not create the managedInstance - only the db.  Are you getting an error trying to use it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the resource type in the ARM template you provided is `Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases`, it will just create the database without creating the managed instance whose type is `Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances`, as shown in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/managedinstances?tabs=json).

Comment: But then how it will know in which managed instance to create new database?

Comment: @hanu, the resource name should be `"name": "{sqlserver name}/{database name}"`.